# Azure SDK for Go - can get a KeyVault but can't get KeyVault.Properties

Tags: azure, go, sdk

I am currently working with the Azure SDK for Go. Everything was going fine until I ran into the following issue:

```
keyVault, err := client.Get(context.Background(), "NAME_OF_RESOURCE_GROUP", "NAME_OF_KEY_VAULT")
```

When I run this:

```
log.Print(*keyVault.Name)
```

It show the name of the Key Vault which is good.

However when I try anything to do with:

`*keyVault.Properties.EnableSoftDelete`

I get - `null`

I can see the Vault Properties on the model:

```
type Vault struct {
    autorest.Response `json:"-"`
    // Properties - Properties of the vault
    Properties *VaultProperties `json:"properties,omitempty"`
    // ID - READ-ONLY; The Azure Resource Manager resource ID for the key vault.
    ID *string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    // Name - READ-ONLY; The name of the key vault.
    Name *string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    // Type - READ-ONLY; The resource type of the key vault.
    Type *string `json:"type,omitempty"`
    // Location - The supported Azure location where the key vault should be created.
    Location *string `json:"location,omitempty"`
    // Tags - The tags that will be assigned to the key vault.
    Tags map[string]*string `json:"tags"`
}
```

But no matter what I try I they are never anything but `null`

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I realised what the issue is.

If EnableSoftDelete is not set or maybe has never been set then instead of this being true:

```
*keyVault.Properties.EnableSoftDelete = false
```

This is true:

```
*keyVault.Properties.EnableSoftDelete = null
```

So here is an Azure REST API response where soft delete is not enabled and has never been disabled:

```
{
"id": "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/rg-prd-aus-dislqmwkcq/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/kv-prd-aus-dislqmwkcq",
"name": "kv-prd-aus-dislqmwkcq",
"type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
"location": "australiasoutheast",
"tags": {
    "example_key_vault_1": "example-kv"
},
"properties": {
    "sku": {
        "family": "A",
        "name": "premium"
    },
    "tenantId": "***",
    "networkAcls": {
        "bypass": "AzureServices",
        "defaultAction": "Deny",
        "ipRules": [
            {
                "value": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
        ],
        "virtualNetworkRules": []
    },
    "accessPolicies": [],
    "enabledForDeployment": false,
    "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
    "enabledForTemplateDeployment": false,
    "vaultUri": "https://***.azure.net/",
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
}
```

}